# Android, toolbar and status bar have the same color

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I managed to make the status bar translucent and now I am facing an issue with it's color. For some reason the status bar has the same color as the toolbar when swipe up.

[image]

DetailsActivity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/md_grey_200">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="com.my.package.FlingBehavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="true"

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/details_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles-v21 :

```
<style name="MyFinalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theme attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

This is what I use to make the status bar translucent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window w = getWindow(); 
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

I tried to change the status bar color to primary_dark in styles-v21 but it didn't worked. Neither has this:

```
 w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            w.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
```

colors.xml ,as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="colorPrimary">#00b386</color>
   <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#008060</color>
   <color name="colorAccent">#00e6ac</color>
</resources>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which color do you want to change and to what color. please specify. post your colors.xml here.

Comment: I want to change the status bar color to a darker green teal. I added the colors.xml

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

**1.** I removed these lines:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window w = getWindow(); 
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

**2.** I added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the `ImageView`, like so:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

**3.** Changed the statusBarColor to transparent:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this color and see what happen

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
```

with

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
```

or you can use theme as like below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You mismatch some color like colorAccent = primary and also colorPrimary=primary?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Same thing happens, the status bar has the same color as the toolbar...Could it be because of the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` ?

Comment: You have to check entire values folder i.e value-21,value23 and i'm not sure about FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS you can read developer.android for this flag

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it to your specified Activity in style-21 package!

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and i see you set this to your `CoordinatorLayout`,it's mean that this view will full_screen ,so when swipe up,the statusBar will show the toolbar's background because it's transparent ..

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

hope to help..

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
<style name="MyFinalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theme attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

**to**

```
<style name="MyFinalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theme attrs -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Makes it worse, the toolbar and the status bar are now white.

Comment: have declare those in style-v21?

Comment: Yes, in styles-v21 / v22 and v23

Comment: Check @AjayPandya 's answer add it to your style file.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have some wrong conception about this coloring thing. i would like to explain to you about its principles.

in colors.xml you have generally 3 colors from starting in any android app. they are -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#12AE90</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

- colorPrimaryDark

this is the color that is topmost color in your activity and this is the bar which contains the network info , time and all other cool stuff. if you want to change its color then change the respective color code in the color.xml .

- colorPrimary

this is the color of the titlebar and this contains your app name or the activity name.if you want to change its color then change the respective color code in the color.xml .

- colorAccent

this is the color of the items inside your activity like buttons and edittext etc. if you want to change its color then change the respective color code in the color.xml .

the color code for different colors can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp).

i think my answer solves your query. please let me know if it does so.

Comment: It doesn't work. I changed all 3 colors, check my colors.xml